# Manually rebuild PyCharm index

Tags: indexing, pycharm

Sometimes PyCharm becomes very slow. And after 20-30 mins of slowness, it rebuilds its index. Are there any ways to manually trigger rebuilding PyCharm indexes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm 4.0.5 hangs on 'scanning files to index' background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030682/pycharm-4-0-5-hangs-on-scanning-files-to-index-background-task)

Answer (score 38):

```
"File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart..."
```

Comment: There isn't a better option than restarting the whole process?