# ctrl+click feature is broken in Django project in Pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

Hi I have a Django project that I could nicely navigate from view, to template file by ctrl+click on the html file.

I made some changes to project and split my setting.py into base, local,production and put them in a settings folder.

I made some changes in settings.py on BASE_DIR to reflect the changes accordingly.
Now the project is working, however ctrl+click feature is broken and not working.
any Idea, why this is lost?

Comment: not sure why got -1. here is simmilar question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749981/pycharm-cannot-find-declaration-to-go-to   why shoot down a question with no reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to point out the new setting folder in Django settings:
[image]