# Django Models objects cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: python, django, object, django-models, pycharm

I have a simple django app. Inside the models.py folder i have:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def get_all(self):
        all = TestModel.objects.all()
        return all
```

Even though I have instances of TestModel in my database (PostgreSQL), the function `get_all` returns `None`. PyCharm helped me in narrowing down the problem by marking `objects` and telling me that it `Cannot find a declaration to go to.` If I create the project with PyCharm Professional through the UI, this problem does not occur. As soon as I open the application through PyCharm Community, the problem appears and does NOT go away by switching back to Professional.

Django version - 3.2.9 and 4.0.0 tested

Questions:

1. How to make the Django recognize `objects` by using PyCharm Community?
2. What is the cause for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749981/pycharm-cannot-find-declaration-to-go-to).

Comment: I tried to invalidate caches and to mark the folder with manage.py as sources root, unfortunately neither worked. The function still believes that the Model has no `objects` property and consequently returns `None`, making queries impossible.

Comment: Try adding `objects = models.Manager()` explicitly to your model.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it did not help as the query still returned None with plenty of instances in the DB :\

Comment: I have never used PyCharm, but from what I found by searching the Community Edition has some problems with Django. You can try looking at [this reference](https://automationpanda.com/2017/09/14/django-projects-in-pycharm-community-edition/), or maybe find some others, and see if you find anything that helps.