# PyCharm not recognizing editable install of Python library in separate projects

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I have two Python projects (txglibrary and txg-application) in separate folders. I am trying to install txglibrary as an editable in my txg-application. Here's my process:

- Create a virtual environment: txg-application-env.
- Activate the virtual environment.
- Navigate to the txglibrary folder.
- Run `pip install -e .` to install txglibrary as an editable.

After completing these steps, my code functions correctly. However, PyCharm does not recognize txglibrary, resulting in a 'Cannot find declaration to go to' error. This issue prevents me from effectively debugging, as I cannot set breakpoints in the txglibrary code when debugging in the txg-application.
Attempts to Resolve:

I have tried the following without success:

- Invalidate Caches in PyCharm.
- Checked the project interpreter, which contains txglibrary with version 0.0.0.
- Various solutions as offered in similar StackOverflow question: [Cannot find declaration to go to, error in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749981/cannot-find-declaration-to-go-to-error-in-pycharm)

  - I added an interpreter to the project
  - Changing file types of .py files where already set correct
  - **Marking Directory as -> Sources Root is not possible, since the txglibrary is contained in a different location than in this project.**

I am using PyCharm Version: 2022.2.3 (Community Edition). In my external libraries, I have the following filepath: `C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\txg-application\Lib\site-packages\txglibrary-0.0.0.dist-info`. However, there is no folder containing actual .py files, which I would expect.